# Extremely high error in the first epochs (Pytorch - image segmentation)

Tags: pytorch, loss-function

Why is the error function of my model on the validation data extremely high in the first epochs when I set my net to eval.

If I use model.eval() the error is greater than 40-50k in the first 4-5 epochs and then drops rapidly to 3-4, but if I leave my net on model.train() the error is only 5-6.

```
def eval_model(DataLoader, model, criterion, device, withStat, withImage):
    model.eval()
    eval_epochen_loss = 0
    img = None
    n_eval = 0
    TP, TN, FP, FN = 0, 0, 0, 0
    stat = None

    for i, data in enumerate(DataLoader):
        dicoms, targets = data
        dicoms, targets = Variable(dicoms.to(device)), Variable(targets.to(device))

        assert targets.shape[1] - 1 == model.n_classes, \
            f'Network has been defined with {model.n_classes} output classes, ' \
            f'but loaded target have {targets.shape[1] - 1} channels. Please check the labeled data or adjust ' \
            f'the network classes. '

        preds = model(dicoms)
        loss = criterion(preds, targets[:, -1, :, :].long())

        eval_epochen_loss += loss.item()
        n_eval += dicoms.shape[0]

        if withStat:
            res = TP_TN_FP_FN_in_batch(targets[:, -1, :, :].cpu().detach().long(), preds.detach().cpu())
            TP += res[0]
            TN += res[1]
            FP += res[2]
            FN += res[3]

    if withStat:
        stat = Statistic(TP, TN, FP, FN)

    if withImage:
        img_np = np.array(draw_images((dicoms, targets[:, -1], preds), outline_bool=True)).transpose(0, 3, 1, 2)
        img = torch.from_numpy(img_np)

    return eval_epochen_loss / n_eval, stat, img
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to diagnose your issue without seeing the model but batch norm behaves differently during eval mode and train mode. This is likely the reason you have this issue. Batchnorm uses the entire training batch to obtain its parameters during training, but uses a stored running mean to be used during validation/testing. It seems this running mean takes a few epochs to converge well for your validation set. Is your data correctly normalised?